# Compare Arrays with Javascript and build another Array

Tags: javascript, json

In Javascript:
I have an existing array like [4,5,6,10] - (These are 'repid').

I have an ajax response like [{"repid":5,"avgAmount":2.5},{"salesrepid":10,"avgAmount":3.0}].

I have to build a third array which will compare the 'repids' of the 2 arrays and build a third array so that it will place a '0' if the repids do not match or else the 'avgAmount' if they match.

So, in my case above, I would 'build' a third array:
[0, 2.5, 0, 3.0]

I've tried many variances of:

```
//need to assign the sales average values to the proper repid
for (var i = 0; i < repIds.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < salesrepids.length; j++) {
         if (repIds[i] == salesrepids[j]) {
              salesvalues.push(key.avgAmount);
              } else { salesvalues.push("0"); }
               };
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show your effort and tell us where you are stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address the correct keys of your objects. And also only add the 0 in case you don't find any matching entry:

```js
var repIds = [4, 5, 6, 10];
var salesrepids = [{"repid": 5, "avgAmount": 2.5}, {"repid": 10, "avgAmount": 3.0}]
var salesvalues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < repIds.length; i++) {
    var noMatch = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < salesrepids.length; j++) {
        if (repIds[i] === salesrepids[j]['repid']) {
            salesvalues.push(salesrepids[j]['avgAmount']);
            noMatch = false;
        }
    }
    if (noMatch) {
        salesvalues.push(0);
    }
}
console.log(salesvalues);
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks Danmoreng.  I see that I need to loop through the second array (the 2nd 'for' loop) looking for a matching repid.  Then, and only then, push a 0 to the new array if no match.  If there is a strict match, push the amount from the second array and flip the flag to nomatch-false.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

Loop through the first array -> Check if the `id` exists in the second array using `find` -> If yes, return it's `avgAmount` else return `0`.

```js
const ids = [4,5,6,10],
   amounts = [{"repid":5,"avgAmount":2.5},{"repid":10,"avgAmount":3.0}];

const output = ids.map(i => {
  const found = amounts.find(a => a.repid === i);
  return found ? found.avgAmount : 0;
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks adiga! I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I'll check this one out as well!

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

```js
  var repids  = [4,5,6,10];
  var returns = [{"repid":5,"avgAmount":2.5},{"salesrepid":10,"avgAmount":3.0}];
  var results = [];
  
  for(var key in returns){
     if(repids.includes(returns[key].repid)){
       results.push(returns[key].repid);
       results.push(returns[key].avgAmount);
     }
     if(repids.includes(returns[key].salesrepid)){
       results.push(returns[key].salesrepid);
       results.push(returns[key].avgAmount);
     }
  }
  console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks mscdeveloper! I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I'll check this one out as well!